# Reveal text, line for line with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

After searching the web, and trying my best, i now ask you.

I have a case, where i need to present some text, with a nice animation.

Like in this jsfiddle, the animation is nice, but it doesn't honor line breaks.

http://jsfiddle.net/Supremacy2k/nedemkgf/

HTML:

```
<div id="text">
 <span>
  In Legends of Old, a great tale of bravery is told.<br>
  About a young warrior, and an unspeakable evil.<br>
 </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var spanWidth = $('#text span').width();
$('#text').animate({
 width: spanWidth
}, 3000);
```

So i kept googling, and found this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Supremacy2k/bzBzL/176/

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
 <div id="title"><span id="name">Lore</span> Says:</div>
 <div id="message"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var timer, fullText, currentOffset, onComplete, wordSet;

function Speak(person, text, callback) {
    $("#name").html(person);
    fullText = text;
    wordSet = text.split(" ");
    currentOffset = 0;
    onComplete = callback;
    timer = setInterval(onTick, 300);
}

function onTick() {
    currentOffset++;
    if (currentOffset == wordSet.length) {
        complete();
        return;
    }
    var text = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < currentOffset; i++){
     text += wordSet[i] + " ";   
    }
    text.trim();
    $("#message").html(text);
}

function complete() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
    $("#message").html(fullText);
    if (onComplete) onComplete();
}

$(".box").click(function () {
    complete();
});

var lore = `
    In Legends of Old, a great tale of bravery is told.<br /> 
  About a young warrior, and an unspeakable evil.<br />
`;

Speak("Lore", lore);
```

That one does honor line breaks, but it has no animation.

Can someone point me in the right direction, of how to combine the two, so it looks like the first jsfiddle, but honors line breaks?

- Regards Kris.

Comment: Managed to get it almost working, but can't get rid of those pesky double quotes br gives with jquery append.
https://jsfiddle.net/Supremacy2k/naLjyLof/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up, fine-tuning what i already had, and this is the result, for anybody else, who might need such a thing.

```js
var lore = {
    book1: {
      chapter1: {
        header: "Prologue",
        content: "In Legends of Old, a great tale of bravery is told. About a young adventurer and a great evil engulfing the land.. BREAK. This tale begins on a wet, windy night...",
        watched: 0,
      },
    },
    book2: "some more lore!",
    show: function(b, c) {
      var loreheader = lore[b][c].header;
      var loretxt = lore[b][c].content;
      $("#lore_head").html(loreheader);
      loretxt = loretxt.replace(". ", ".. ");
      var arr = loretxt.split(". ");
      var timer2 = 0;
      var timerAdd;

      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var num = i;
        var targetNum = i + 1;
        var target = 'span#line' + num;
        var line = arr[num];
        timer = 4000;
        timer2 += 500;
        if(line.length < 6) {
          timer = 50;
          line = " ";
          timerAdd = 50;
        } else {
          timerAdd = timer;
        }
        lore.animate(num, targetNum, target, timer, timer2, line);
        timer2 += timerAdd;
      }
    },
    animate: function(num, targetNum, target, timer, timer2, text) {
      var textspan = '<span id=\"line' + num + '\">' + text + '</span><br />';
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("div#lore_content").append($.trim(textspan));
        var testWidth = $(target).width();
        $(target).animate({
          width: testWidth
        }, timer, "linear");
      }, timer2);
    }
  };
  
  lore.show("book1","chapter1");
```

```css
div#lore_content span {
  width: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lore_head"></div>
<div id="lore_content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript:

```
var storyHTML=
  "In Legends of Old, a great tale of bravery is told.<br>"+
  "About a young warrior, and an unspeakable evil.<br>";
function tellStory(storyDivId,storyHTML) {
  var storyDiv=document.getElementById(storyDivId);
  var storyArray=storyHTML.split("<br>").join("*<br>*").split(" ").join("* *").split("*")
  var atWord=0;
  var id=setInterval(speak, 100);
  function speak() {
    if(atWord<storyArray.length) {
      storyDiv.innerHTML+=storyArray[atWord];
      atWord++
    } else {
      clearInterval(id);
    }
  }
}
```

html:

```
<div id="storyDiv"></div>
```

Use in javascript:

- `tellStory("storyDiv",storyHTML)`.
- `tellStory("storyDiv","In Legends of Old, a great tale of bravery is told.<br>"+
  "About a young warrior, and an unspeakable evil.<br>")`.

Comment: That does not have the animation im looking for. :(

Comment: @Supremacy2k please explain.  I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
div.line {
  width: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="story">
  <div class="line">In Legends of Old, a great tale of bravery is told.</div>
  <div class="line">About a young warrior, and an unspeakable evil.</div>
  <div class="line">In Legends of Old, a great tale of bravery is told.</div>
  <div class="line">About a young warrior, and an unspeakable evil.</div>
  <div class="line">In Legends of Old, a great tale of bravery is told.</div>
  <div class="line">About a young warrior, and an unspeakable evil.</div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function animate(divId) {
  var div=document.getElementById(divId);
  var lineCount=div.children.length;
  var lineNumber=0;
  var width=10;
  var id;
  if(lineNumber<lineCount) {
    line=div.children[lineNumber];
    id=setInterval(speak, 20);
  };
  function speak() {
    if(width>=100) {
      clearInterval(id);
      lineNumber++;
      if(lineNumber<lineCount) {
        line=div.children[lineNumber];
        width=10;
        id=setInterval(speak, 20);
      };
    } else {
      width++; 
      line.style.width=width+'%'; 
    }
  }
}
```

Start animation with:

```
animate("story");
```

Hope this is better.  I looked in your fiddle...